# What does "Baggage Allowance 1PC" mean on an SAS flight reservation?

Tags: luggage, airlines, sas

I booked a flight through the Corte Ingles Viajes site, going from Oslo to Barcelona with SAS. It says in the confirmation email that I have a 1-piece baggage allowance. Does it mean that I am allowed to check in a 23-kg piece of luggage and carry a hand luggage?

Comment: "PC" most likely means "piece", and therefore you are allowed 1 piece of checked luggage.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That is correct

Answer (score 10):

According to [Seatguru](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/SAS_Airlines/baggage.php) and [FlySAS](http://www.flysas.com/en/us/Travel-info/Baggage/Checked-baggage/), on SAS you're always allowed a carry-on luggage and at least one piece of checked luggage. So yes, you're correct

> Simple rules. SAS always allows you to take at least one bag (up to 23 kg/51 lbs.) with you, plus one cabin baggage item up to 8 kg/18 lbs. completely free. If you are traveling in SAS Plus or SAS Business, you can take even more – consult the table below.
>
> ```
> SAS GO        SAS PLUS        SAS Business
>                               to/from the US/Asia
> 1 piece       2 pieces        2 pieces 
> 23 kg/51 lbs  23 kg/51 lbs    32 kg/71 lbs
> ```

Comment: I suggest you quote the relevant parts of the links in your answer since links are prone to 404  oblivion. ;)

Comment: @JoErNanO quite right, updated

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! it helps also for my further ticket purchase :)

Comment: @Estela glad I could help, consider marking the answer accepted as to help others in the future :)